# How to ensure object has only one thread

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

I have a following code:

```
class Service {
public:
    void start(); // creates thread which creates window and goes to message loop
    void stop();  // sends WM_CLOSE message to thread window
private:
    HANDLE hMutex;
    HANDLE hThread;
    HWND   hWindow;
};
```

I want my class to perform behaviour like this:

```
Service obj;
obj.start(); // new thread
obj.start(); // do nothing because thread already exists
```

Now I'm stuck on question which handle to cover by mutex:

```
void Service::start() {
    // check if service is already running
    if (/*!!*/) // what should I check: (hThread != NULL)? or (hWindow != NULL)?
        return; // no need to create another thread
    else
        hThread = CreateThread(...);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call start only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if `hThread` is a valid handle or not:

```
if (hThread != NULL)
    return;
else
    hThread = CreateThread(...);
```

[`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a valid handle if the thread is successfully created, so make sure you have proper handling after your call to `CreateThread`. You will also need to ensure you initialise `hThread` to `NULL` in your constructor:

```
Service::Service() : hMutex(NULL), hThread(NULL) etc...
{
}
```

If you were using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead, you could simply check whether the thread was [`joinable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable):

```
class Service
{
public:
    void start();
private:
    std::thread thread;
};
Service::start()
{
    if (thread.joinable())
        return;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a race condition here under these conditions:

1. Thread A executes `if (hThread != NULL)`
2. Thread A sleeps and thread B starts.
3. Thread B executes `if(hThread != NULL)`

`//Both threads now think they're the only one running??`

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that a single thread is calling `start()`, and the OP didn't want `CreateThread` to create multiple threads. If there are multiple threads calling `start()` then more handling would be needed.

Comment: I have no idea why you got downvoted, you answered exactly my question :) Thanks. Can you also take a look at my stop() function: `Service::stop() {
 if (WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
  CloseHandle(hThread);
  hThread = NULL;
 }
}`

Comment: I almost deleted after the DV, but I was quite certain I was answering what you were asking. Some people must've misinterpreted what you wanted. With regards to `stop()`, be aware that [`CloseHandle` doesn't terminate a thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx). You will need to call [`ExitThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/ms686724(v=vs.85).aspx) first.

Comment: Other answers about making my class thread safe and it wasn't my original question

Comment: @Stephan Why call start twice?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, to prevent wrong usage om my class I want to make sure that if user accidentally calls start twice - he won't get memleak

Comment: @StephanLeila: A debug assertion should suffice. If the user of your library writes buggy code, let them have a buggy application. A library's job is not to fix the clients' buggy code.

Comment: Exactly. Make it a rule that start is only called once. Don't try to detect code that fails to do so because it makes a total mess of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the state of the thread handle *hThread*, if it's signaled then it means that the thread is terminated:

```
DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject( hThread, 0);

if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    // the signal is sent and therefore the thread has been terminated
}
else {
    // the signal is not sent and hThread is alive
}
```

Note that the second parameter is the timeout and need to be set to zero for non-blocking call.

You can inspect the detailed [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would take the RAII way and create the thread in the constructor and close it in the destructor. The main advantages are that you can't forget to close the service(Even when there's an exception), and that the constructor can only be called once and only by one thread at a time.

Comment: Very good point. Unless there's a specific reason to require a `start()` and `stop()`, definitely prefer RAII!

Comment: I'm using lazy instantiation, so constructor of `Service class` doesn't do anything. And all the heavy work would be performed on demand (i.e. calling `start()` )