# How to wait for window to be created in other thread

Tags: c++, oop, winapi

I have the following code:

```
class Service {
public:
    void start();
    void stop();
private:
    HANDLE hThread;
    HWND   hWindow;
};

void Service::start() {
    hThread = CreateThread(...); // creates window and goes on to message loop
}

void Service::stop() {
    // !!! wait for m_hwnd to become valid
    // send signal to thread to stop
    PostMessage(m_hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    // wait to thread to die
    ::WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Client code:

```
Service obj;
obj.start();
obj.stop();
```

The problem is when main thread calls `stop()`, child thread didn't create window yet and there's no message loop to process `WM_CLOSE` message. How should I wait for window to be created?
Function `WaitOnAddress` seems to do what I need, but it's win8 and upper and I need something about winxp level

Comment: @MNS,sadly, it doesn't wait

Comment: Use a synchronization object (e.g. an event).

Comment: @JonathanPotter can you elaborate ?

Comment: Did you make a new account? http://stackoverflow.com/users/5557632/stephan-leila. I'm guessing you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686786/how-to-ensure-object-has-only-one-thread?rq=1

Comment: @Tas yep, forgot email, lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Event objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx) are a form of inter-thread/inter-process communication. They let one thread wait for an arbitrary event to occur in another thread before proceeding.

Basically you want something like this:

```
class Service {
    HANDLE hThread;
    HANDLE hEvent;
    HWND   hWindow;
};

void Service::start() {
    // create event
    hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr); 

    hThread = CreateThread(...); // creates window and goes on to message loop

    // wait for window
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hEvent);
}


void thread_function(...)
{
    // create window, etc

    // signal parent to continue
    SetEvent(hEvent);
}
```